# Return all table's rows in a Select field laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to return to my select all the elements of my 'categories' table except the current line.
I didn't find anything about this on the internet, so I'm coming to you.

My current item for Select:

```
Select::make('Parent Category')
                ->options([

            ])
                ->displayUsingLabels(),
```

And this is the head of my categories table:

[image: Categories table]

Comment: I use https://github.com/dillingham/nova-ajax-select   .You create an api endpoint and return Category::all();    However, is this a case where you could use a BelongsTo relationship?

Comment: @Cameron have you used this with pivot tables?

Comment: @dan I believe it's the same in theory, you pass a param to a custom API route, fetch your pivit data and return a response.  He has some examples in the git repo readme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you have a self referrencing relationship between the Category model, and itself such as

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

In Nova usually, you would express the relationship between the Child and its Parent not as a Select field, but as a BelongsTo such as:

```
    BelongsTo::make('Parent Category', 'parent', Category::class)->searchable()->nullable(),
```

But you could use the Select field to have a pre-loaded array of Categories so you can filter out the current category onlyOnForms().

You can do it this way:

```
 public function fields(Request $request)
 {
     
        $fields = [
            
            // [ All your fields ]
            
            // We'll use a Select but onlyOnForms to show all categories but current category when in Forms
            Select::make('Parent', 'parent_id')->options(Category::where('id', '!=', request()->resourceId)->pluck('name', 'id'))->onlyOnForms(),

            // Use a BelongsTo to show the parent category when in Details page
            BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', Category::class)->searchable()->nullable()->showOnDetail()->hideWhenCreating()->hideWhenUpdating(),
       
        ];


}
```

Comment: And what if you want to add another Select for children based on parent?